# Using a paged FlatList, how to get an event on visible page changed?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am building a simple horizontal React Native FlatList with paging enabled:

```
<FlatList
   horizontal={true}
   pagingEnabled={true}
   data={...some data...}
   renderItem={({item}) => {...some rendering...}}
   onViewableItemsChanged={(info) => {... handling ...}}
 />
```

I would like to get called back only after a new page in the list has been made visible.  The behavior that I am seeking is that, as the user swipes the list left and right, the list will page through the items and I want the callback to fire once with the visible items.

The `onViewableItemsChanged` props is called on every change in visible items which is not what I am looking for, unless I keep track on which page the items belong to.

I am looking for a `onViewablePageChanged` type of callback.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The solution I used was to track the viewable items against the overall list of items to determine the "page" number of viewable items.

By using `pagingEnabled`, the list will only show pages.
However `onViewableItemsChanged` is called back on every changes to the viewable items.  By comparing the viewable items againts the list of items, one can figure out on which "page" the FlatList is.

This requires that one knows how many items can be displayed in the view.  Either calculated based on layout or set in the View and FlatList rendering.

Here's an example:

```
onViewableItemsChanged = ({viewableItems}) => {

  // Get the first viewable item
  const firstViewableItem = viewableItems[0].key;

  // Get its index into the items
  const index = this.state.items.findIndex(item => item.key === firstViewableItem);

  // If the index is a multiple of the number of items displayable on the screen
  // by checking for a reminder on the modulo operation
  if ((index % NB_ITEMS_SCREEN) === 0) {

    // get page
    const currentPage = index / NB_ITEMS_SCREEN;
    if (currentPage !== this.state.currentPage) {
      // Do something and update currentPage in this.state
    }
  }
}

<FlatList
   data={this.state.items}
   horizontal={true}
   pagingEnabled={true}
   renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
   onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
/>
```

See this snack

https://snack.expo.io/@visto9259/flatlist-onviewableitemschanged-example

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve visible items by using below code. Try this.

```
//Method to invoke when item change
onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
      console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
      console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed);
   }

render () => {
    return (
    ...
    <FlatList
        horizontal={true}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        data={...some data...}
        renderItem={({item}) => {...some rendering...}}
        onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged }
        viewabilityConfig={{
          itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
        }}
     /> 
    ....
   )}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I was not looking for.  I would have liked for "onViewableItemsChanged" to be called only when a "page" of items have changed.